# Is there a way to test the best fit of combination of ratios to fit inside an overarching ratio?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

We have a problem we are trying to solve where we have a number of different containers. Each container can hold a number of different items (call them "item $A$" through to "item $H$"). Each container can handle a different ratio of the items before it is full. So taking just three of the containers the ratios the can handle may be:

**Container $1$** may be able to hold the items in the ratio like below:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
1  2  3  3  3  3  2  1
```

**Container $2$** may be able to hold the items in the ratio like below:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
1  2  3  4  4  3  2  1
```

**Container $3$** may be able to hold the items in the ratio like below:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4
```

What we need to try and find out is how to best fit packs of items with smaller ratios with a maximum number of items (say $5$ or $6$) into the containers. We can find all the different permutations of packs using combinatorics. We have a limit that out of all of the pack ratio permutations we can only select $3$ or $4$ different ones to use, so have to discard the worst fits and keep the best $3$ or $4$.

What we are struggling with is a technique that can test for the best of the smaller packs into the larger containers that is both accurate and performant. *Currently we have one or the other!*

Is there a way to do this$?$

Comment: As I mentioned on Programmers, where you first posted this, the word *ratio* is confusing.  Let me try to describe this in terms of a limit on number of items.  Can we say that Container 1 holds one of A, two of B, three each of C,D,E,F, and two of G and one of H?  It holds those ten items simultaneously?  And, presumably, it could hold any smaller combination of such items?

Comment: Yes, but we need to fill the container not with single items, but with packs of yet to be defined ratios. For example one pack with 1 of A, 2 of B and 1 of C will fit in container 1 and 2 but not container 3.

We are limited to only three or four different pack "shapes" but need to get the best fit available across all containers with only these three different shaped "packs"

Comment: There are a number of details to be supplied before your problem can be formulated for an algorithm.  You say "we need to fill the container" with "packs... yet to be defined".  What criterion is used to judge which choice of three (or four) pack shapes is best?  Do all the containers need to be exactly filled, or is a solution that leaves room in some containers for single items useful?

Comment: The container types and pack shapes are called [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) because an item can appear more than once in the container or pack.  One way to think about the ideal solution to this problem is to ask for a common partition of the container types into no more than four pack shapes.  In the example given it is possible to do this with $$(1,1,2,2,3,3,2,1), (0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0), (0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0), (0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1)$$

Comment: @hardmath - Yes the solution will be permitted to leave not fill the containers completely and leave "gaps" that can be filled with singles later.

We don't know what shape of the packs we are going to use yet. We are using this to find the best fit of packs into the various containers we have.

So for a given set containers with different shapes, and given that we only want three or four different pack shapes, what are the shapes of these packs which will fill the containers in the most efficient way?

Comment: Unfortunately although I am a programmer and can probably program an absolute brute force technique for getting to this answer it will not be performant. As I don't have a maths level of anything more than about high school this is kind of out of my depth.

Comment: I'm asking what criterion makes one choice of pack shapes more efficient than another.  The criterion needs to be stated to pose a mathematical problem.

Comment: Basically the fewer packs we can fit in each container (taking that there could be 10s of different container shapes) the better as the manual loading and unloading of the packs from the containers needs to be as efficient as possible. Also loading and unloading of ths singles that in fill the gaps left between the packs is not as efficient either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take as the first goal a statement of the mathematical problem to be solved, and then make some suggestions about a *greedy algorithm* to approximate the solution.

As with many combinatorial problems, we can separate out the hard part, here the selection of up to four "packs" useful in loading containers, and the easy part, assessing the "goodness" of any possible selection.  This latter part is not very clear in the Question statement, so I will propose an objective that is relatively easy to compute and arguably representative of what the real world objective is.

Suppose that the packs $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$ have been chosen as multisets of the available items.  We pose the following "inner" problem.

We define a cost of filling a specified number $f_i$ of each kind of container $C_i$, using combinations of packs $P_k$ and individual items $j$ ("item A to item H" in the Question statement).

Let $w_k$, $k = 1,2,3,4$, be the cost of loading pack $P_k$ into a container.  We assume this is a common cost for any container $C_i$ into which $P_k$ will fit, but the value could be made to depend on the container as well as the pack, or simply to be a constant depending on neither.  Also let $w_0$ be the cost for loading any individual item in a container.

We want to minimize the total cost $T = \sum_i f_i L_i$ of loading all containers, where $L_i$ is the cost of loading one container $C_i$.  Notice that achieving this minimum total cost $T$ amounts to minimizing the cost $L_i$ of filling each different container, given the available packs and itemized costs.

Because the minimization is done for each container type $C_i$, these are small [integer linear programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).  Although there may be tens of different container types (per the Question statement), solving the least cost ways of loading each are fully decoupled computations.

**Example** Taking the itemized and pack loading costs $w_0 = w_1 = w_2 = w_3 = w_4$ to be equal and positive results in finding how to fill each container $C_i$ with the fewest items and packs, counting both items and packs equally.

The outer problem is selecting which packs $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$ will result in the minimum total cost $T$.  Consideration of all possible packs, even though only four at a time are used, seems fairly impractical.  We therefore propose a procedure that searches for good choices of packs based on a greedy heuristic.

By greedy we mean choosing the first pack $P_1$ so that $|P_1| \sum_{i\in S_1} f_i$, the largest number of items coverable by a pack, is maximized.  Here $S_1$ denotes the set of indexes $i$ for which $P_1 \subseteq_m C_i$ (where the subscript $m$ reminds us we are dealing with multisets rather than simple sets).

Remove as many copies of $P_1$ from the various $C_i$ containers as possible (at least one copy for each $i$ in $S_i$), and repeat the process with the redacted container definitions $C_i'$ to choose the second pack $P_2$.  And so on, until all four packs are defined.

At certain points in this search there may be more than one choice of $P_k$ that maximizes the corresponding coverage $\sum_{i\in S_k} f_i$.  If computational time permits, some or all of these variations should be explored.

Comment: Looks very promising, thank you. I will feed back once we have managed to implement that.

Comment: I will also try my hand at implementing it.  Do you have a more realistic set of containers to work with?  With three containers and four packs we can obviously "cheat" the solution.

Comment: Thank you.

I haven't got any "true" representations of the actual containers but we do have test cases which need to pass so I will try and post some of those.

For instance Case 1 the container is
`A B C D E F
2 4 6 6 4 2`

and the two packs are Pack A and Pack B:

`A B C D E F
1 2 3 3 2 1`

`A B C D E F
1 4 6 6 4 1`

and in this case we need to make sure that 2 of pack A is chosen as that will leave no need for singles to "in-fill"

I will try and get document more of the scenarios in a format that reads well on this site.

EDIT: Sorry the website just does not render newlines well.

Comment: @Dib: Right, you cannot use newlines in Comments.